# Django queryset has no attribute when using select related

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to using `select_related` to queryset, and it returns queryset has no attribute when using select related. I made two models, and one model has foreignkey column, it is 1:1.

models

```
class User(models.Model):
   name = Charfield()

class Item(models.Model):
   user = models.ForegnKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_item_set', null=True)
```

When I try this queryset, it says queryset does not have select related.

```
users = User.objects.get(id=pk).select_related('user_item_set')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you misunderstood the usage of [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

> Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query.

It can be used on `Item` model (the model which defines the `ForegnKey` field) and not `User` model.

---

What you need to use is [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). Something like this:

```
users = User.objects.get(id=pk).prefetch_related('item_set')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes I changed it from select_related to prefetch_related, but still got same error

Comment: You also need to change from `user_item_set` to `item_set`.